# How to randomly make appear one by one images from a map with fade?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, fade

I am currently creating a logo wall for a website.
I managed with a map to display them randomly but now I would like to be able to make them appear one by one and randomly ( for example : image 1, image 6, image 3,...) and also leave them visible once they have appeared.

I guess I have to set their opacity to 0 and then make their opacity to 1 but I don't see how to do this in a random way.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react"

const logoImages = [
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/altiplan.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/ametis.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/amplitrain.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/ar.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/artau.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/assaabloy.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/bag.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/bea.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/besix.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/bombardier.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/bouygues.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/ca.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/cartel.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/citymall.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
  {
    image: "/assets/img/companies/coyote.png",
    src: "Michelin",
  },
];

function shuffleMap(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array
  /*array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
  return array*/
}

const Image = ({image, src}) => {
  return (
    <div className='box'>
      <div className='content'>
        <img src={image} alt={src}/>
      </div>

      {/*language=CSS*/}
      <style jsx>{`
        .box {
            min-width: 150px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            background: #000;
        }

        img {
            width: 120px;
            filter: grayscale(1) invert(100%);
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
}

const allImages = shuffleMap(logoImages.map((companies, index) => {
  return <Image key={companies.src+index} {...companies}/>
}));

const LogoWall = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {
        allImages
      }
      {/*language=CSS*/}
      <style>{`
        .container {
            width: 100vw;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-content: space-around;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  )
};
export default LogoWall
```

Comment: choose random, remove that item, repeat, if you did something then show your code

Comment: show code if you want assistance

Comment: @JoeLloyd I edit my post

Comment: @EugenSunic i added my code if you want to see

Comment: would have been better if you placed inside a stackblitz, online so that it compiles...

Comment: @EugenSunic https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-7kisy
Here is a simplified example oh what my code did

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you execute a interval after displaying your images

1. All your images are black due to opacity 0 and randomly stacked
2. Show the first image immediately because of 0*1000=0seconds
3. The following images will appear one by one with 1 second interval

Code:

```
logoImages.forEach((x, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    x.style.opacity = 1
  }, i * 1000)
})
```

Comment: So i need to replace my logoImages.map with the forEach ?

Comment: no, you need to do it after that, because your map will display the array of images on the view, you could try and implement the functionality in the map

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but the forEach returns "undefined."

Comment: you are not supposed to return anything from forEach just modify the existing elements. I'll check it in the evening if no one replies till.

Comment: Yes, I mean, when i do my console.log, it returns undefined for the forEach

Comment: If you have a spare moment, could you tell me how to do that, because I really can't, thank you.